# Speech recognition , where does the recorded audio go?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text

im working on a voice recognition application, where user will say a sentence or anything, and it will be converted into text.... (the conversion voice to text happens via google)

my question is,,, when the person speaks, where is the file/buffer that saves or records his voice(speech)? (before Google takes it and converts it)

and is it possible to get a hold of this file or buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes for version less than 4 (don't know about 3) it is on `onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)`. I n version 4 (ICS) there is nothing returns there.